# Vertx not able to handle internal code error to client automatically

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus

I have a verticle which accepts REST request, get data from other verticle through event bus and respond back to client.

```
vertx.exceptionHandler(event -> logger.error("Vertx exception ", event));    

router.get("/api/v1/:param").handler(this::routerHandler);


public void routerHandler(RoutingContext rc) {
     vertx.eventBus().request("data", param,
                result -> {
                    if (result.succeeded()) {
                        logger.info("Request handled successfully");
                        // intentionally creating exception body() will return String
                        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) result.result().body();
                         rc.response().end(jsonObject)
                    }else{
                        logger.error("Request failed");
                 }
}
```

When a exception is raised it is printed in exception handler that I setup in vertx instance but after that the vertx is not reporting back the exception immediately to client instead it waits for timeout(30 secs) to occur.

I tried attaching error handler to router object and failure handler to route object but nothing helps to report the exception immediately to client. I know I can have a try catch and report the error in catch block. But I want know if there is any other way to handle this like Servlet or Spring MVC reports back to client even though the exception is not handled in code.

```
router.errorHandler(500,routingContext -> {
            System.out.println(routingContext.failed());
           routingContext.response().end("Exception ");
        });

router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create()).failureHandler(routingContext -> {
```

Answer (score 1):

Uncaught exceptions are reported to the context `exceptionHandler`. By default it prints the exception to the console.

You can [configure it](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html#exceptionHandler-io.vertx.core.Handler-) but you will not get a reference to the corresponding HTTP request anyway (the exception may come from different things).

Most problems like this are usually found during unit/integration/acceptance testing.

And for the remainders you could set a timeout handler on your router definition to make sure the request is ended before the default 30 seconds.

If you don't want to miss any uncaught exception, you should switch to the [Vert.x Rxified API](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java2/#_rxified_api). When using RxJava, any exception thrown will be reported to the subscriber.

Comment: I have already configured the exceptionHandler and it is printing out the exception details, but I couldn't not end the response with exception details. And on timeout handler, it looks like triggering a static timeout so it won't timeout when exception occurs right?